# PHP Warning: Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, web-hosting

has anyone encountered this problem when launching your application in a browser? I receive this error in my error_log file each time i launch my application. I never had this issue on my local host. Currently my application is hosted in shared hosting. I have already stripped down my index page to an empty page and tried loading it and i still see this error.
I have been searching for a solution in several forums, but nothing really seems to fix the problem. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: What error, caused from what code? Have asked your hosting company if caused by a piece of software they support?

Comment: This is the error - PHP Warning: Module 'zip' already loaded in Unknown on line 0. The error_log will show this message each time i launch my application. I have not asked them as i assumed it might be caused by me. Perhaps i should bring this up to them. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your question is to vague for us to answer as is. It could be that you are trying to access a resource from an incorrect path, with no code we can't tell what the `zip` usage is..

Comment: There is no code at all. Im just accessing my website, "somesite.com/subdomain1/subdomain2/index.php" via  a browser. The index.php file is totally empty. However, if i go to my public_html folder, i see that error_log is populated with the warning mentioned just now.

Comment: If you have access to the server, please show us the code in "somesite.com/.../index.php".

Comment: If there is no code this is not an issue for SO. I'd contact your hosting company, sounds like they f'd something up.

Comment: Yes probably, i will check with them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `php.ini` file (if possible).  Most likely the directive to enable the `zip` extension was specified twice.  Here's the directive to look for:

```
extension=zip
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the web hosting. I told them and they fixed it. Hope this helps anyone who face similar problem.